# Why is property unaccessible from the setter defined on prototype

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function Test2() {
  this.data = 1;
  this.unaccesible = 7;
}

Object.defineProperty(Test2.prototype, "data", {
  get: function() {
    return this.data;
  },
  set: function(nv) {
    // here this.unaccesible is undefined - why?
    console.log(this.unaccesible);
  }
});

var o = new Test2();
o.data = 2;
```

Why the property is not available inside the setter?

```
console.log(this.unaccesible);
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/uu0d5dgb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the instance of Test2 is created and line 2 is executed, which is  `this.data = 1`, this is defined and it has prototype which  has "data" property but the instance itself doesn't have "data" yet. That's why prototype's data-property setter method is called and it's happening before `this.unaccesible = 7`. that is why this.unaccesible is undefined at this point

Answer (score 2):

Because you define a property on the prototype, not an instance of Test2. `this.data` is only accessible because you are defining a property `data`. It's not the same `data` as the one set in the constructor of Test2.

Comment: The property `unaccesible` is defined on the instance of `Test2`, not prototype

Comment: @Maximus, what you think is the "data"-property on the instance, is instead the `data-setter` inherited from the prototype. The moment the constructor is called, `this` already has all the properties and methods it inherits from the prototype.

Comment: @Thomas, didn't excatly understood your comment. My problem is `unaccesible` property, not `data`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate `Object.defineProperty` for each variable.
Check out the following fiddle for code example with comments. Hope this answers your query.

[JSfiddle example for the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/e3s4faya/1/)

OR Check out the same code below

```
            function Test2() {
              this.data = 1;
              this.unaccesible = 5;
            }

            Object.defineProperty(Test2.prototype, "unaccesible", {
              get: function() {
                return this.data;
              },
              set: function(nv) {
                // here this.unaccesible is undefined - why?
                // You cannot access "unaccesible" directly as the parameter for the
                // setter function is nv.
                var test = nv;
                alert("Unaccessible:" + test);
              }
            });
            // Use object.defineProperty for each variable as follows to set data value
            Object.defineProperty(Test2.prototype, "data", {
              get: function() {
                return this.data;
              },
              set: function(nv) {
                // here this.unaccesible is undefined - why?
                // You cannot access "unaccesible" directly as the parameter for the
                // setter function is nv.
                var test = nv;
                alert("Data:" + test);
              }
            });

            var o = new Test2();
            //This sets the value of unaccesible to 2 after the intial value 5 is stored.
            o.unaccesible = 6;
            //This sets the value of data to 2 after the intial value 1 is stored.
            // This is executed after unaccesible
            o.data = 2;
```